# segmentation fault when trying to cin into a string?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Hi need help with this segmentation fault don't know why i get it

```
Movie *newMovie = (Movie*) malloc(sizeof(Movie));
cout << "\nEnter the next movie title:   ";
cin >> newMovie->title;

class Movie {
  public:
    Movie();
    std::string title;
    int year;
    GenreType genre;
};
```

I checked dgb and segmentation fault comes at the cin line any suggestions? btw title is an instance of Movie type and is std::string

Comment: After you provide `class Movie`, we will probably see that `title` is a `char` pointer which you need to initialize using `malloc`

Comment: Don't use `malloc` to allocate C++ objects. Use `new`. `malloc` won't call the constructor. In this case that leaves `title` uninitialized.

Comment: updated with Movie class didnt use char pointer

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `malloc` in C++ unless you really know you need it (hint: you don't).

`malloc` allocates memory, but it doesn't call any constructors - it just gives you a chunk of bytes to treat as you see fit. Pretending there's an object in these bytes when none was constructed doesn't work.

So just do this:

```
Movie *newMovie = new Movie();
cout << "\nEnter the next movie title:   ";
cin >> newMovie->title;
```

And do you need dynamic allocation in the first place? Why not just:

```
Movie newMovie;
cout << "\nEnter the next movie title:   ";
cin >> newMovie.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple amd safe way to do this would be not to use dynamic allocation:

```
Movie newMovie;
cout << "\nEnter the next movie title:   ";
cin >> newMovie.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Movie newMovie;
cout << "\nEnter the next movie title ";
cin >> newMovie.title;
```

will do the trick